# Python: How to get the actual string from the list object that matches with the given string?

Tags: python

I have python code and i am checking if string exists in a given list object and my checking is not case sensitive as shown below.

```
myTest = "checKING"

lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('FullList.txt')]
if myTest.lower() in [x.lower() for x in lines]:
  print("String exist: found")
```

Since this check is not case sensitive so my question is how can i retrieve the string from the list object "lines" that actually matches with the "myTest" string variable?

For e.g. if the "lines" object contains string "CHECKING" than the above condition will pass. How can I retrieve the string "CHECKING" which help passing above "if" condition?

Comment: Do you want only the first match or all matches?

Answer (score 4):

If you want only the first match, simply unroll the comprehension, then you can `break` after a match.

```
test = myTest.lower()
for line in lines:
    if line.lower() == test:
        print(line)
        break
```

This also makes your program more efficient by avoiding creating an unnecessary list. Plus the simpler structure is easier to read.

---

Although, if you don't actually need `lines`, just the matching line, then you can unroll *both* comprehensions.

```
test = myTest.lower()
with open('FullList.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.lower() == test:
            print(line)
            break
```

Again, avoiding an unnecessary list would make your program more efficient.

Comment: I could do lopp and check line by line but this path i don't want to take. I want to use some rich methods like "in" or filter e.t.c.

Comment: @Ammad Then you can use a comprehension filter like in Nick's answer.

Comment: @Ammad I edited the answer to clarify how this solution is better if you want only the first match

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over  `lines`, finding the words that match and adding them to an output list:

```
lines = ['CHECKING', 'word', 'Checking', 'CHecKIng', 'xyzzy']
myTest = 'checKING'
myTestlower = myTest.lower()
match = [x for x in lines if x.lower() == myTestlower]
print(match)
```

Output:

```
['CHECKING', 'Checking', 'CHecKIng']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `next` function with a generator expression instead:

```
match = next((line for line in map(str.rstrip,
    open('FullList.txt')) if myTest.lower() == line), None)
if match:
    print('Found:', match)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's always using a regexp:

```
import re

myTest = "checKING"

with open('FullList.txt') as lines:
  for line in lines:
    if re.search(myTest, line, re.IGNORECASE):
      print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this, I was just curious whether it works. Although... maybe in a year or so this will be considered normal. Right now the walrus is still new. But really I think the proper way is a `for` loop (by now posted by wjandrea as an answer).

```
>>> myTest = "checKING"
>>> lines = ['foobar', 'CHECKING', 'checking']
>>> if myTest.lower() in ((match := x).lower() for x in lines):
        print('found:', match)

found: CHECKING
```

Comment: if myTest.lower() in ((match := x).lower() for x in lines):
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Ammad Update your Python then.

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2. It;s not supported?

Comment: Wow that's *really* old. Almost four years. Like I said, the walrus is new. Introduced in Python 3.8 a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you *want* a case-insensitive search or not, but if you want one, you can just use

```
matches = [x for x in lines if x.lower() == myTest.lower()]
if len(matches) is 0:
    print("Could not find the string")
else:
    print("Found string ", matches[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `lower()` the words before comparing, i.e.:

```
myTest = "checKING".lower()
with open('FullList.txt') as f:
    print([x.strip() for x in f if x.strip().lower() == myTest])
    # ['checKING']
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/d3f33e27f2)

Comment: How would an in your opinion "constructive" comment on a non-answer answer look like, and how was your previous wrong claim that **I** didn't understand the question constructive?

Comment: Where's your answer?

Comment: Higher on this page?

Comment: it's the one that says: "***Don't do this, I was just curious whether it works.***"?

Comment: Yep. Although the in my opinion proper answer is what I wrote in the very first comment under the question: "Use a `for` loop?". Which has by now been posted as an answer by wjandrea.